# Cannot send mail with yii2 swiftmailer

Tags: php, yii2, smtp, swiftmailer, mailer

I get error when trying send mail with Yii::$app->mailer->compose() function. This error appears when trying to connect smtp server, so I provide error message and mailer YII2 configuration

> Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8
>   Username and Password not accepted.
>   Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 59sm3639427wrc.23 -> gsmtp"

Here is params from config/common.php file:

```
'mailer'       => [
        'class'            => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'transport'        => [
            'class'      => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'port'       => '587',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
            'username' => 'myemailbox@yahoo.com',
            'password' => 'myemailpass',
            'host' => 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com',
        ],
    ],
```

I already enabled "Allow apps that use less secure sign in" function in Yahoo account settings. Trying "app password" option but got the same result.
Before using yahoo smtp I tried it the same way with google smtp. Error message still refers to the https://support.google.com page. Is it possible Apache cached login and pass to smtp server?

Of course I checked google support page and followed instructions included https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this case, but didn`t detect what exactly was the cause. Maybe there was some sort of cache of config error.
So I put this direct setting right before compose function:

```
\Yii::$app->mailer->setTransport([
        'class'      => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
        'port'       => '587',
        'encryption' => 'tls',
       'username' => 'myemailbox@yahoo.com',
        'password' => 'myemailpass',
        'host' => 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com',
    ]);
```

And it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

try changing port

```
'mailer'       => [
        'class'            => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'transport'        => [
            'class'      => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'port'       => '465',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
            'username' => 'myemailbox@yahoo.com',
            'password' => 'myemailpass',
            'host' => 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com',
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: the error he mentioned is related to bad credentials i think.